# How to treat 2 Directories as one in the command line

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-arguments, zsh, directory

I have a script, which takes a list of directories and compares their number of files. What I would like is to sometimes group two or more directories to be treated as one by the script. Of course I could modify the script but I would prefer to do this grouping in the command line.

```
$ ./myscript.sh {dir1 dir2} dir3 dir4 ...
```

should be treated as if {dir1 dir2} was the (mathematical) union of the elements of both directories.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Could you show myscript.sh content? I think you can do what you want just double quoting the dirs like this: ./myscript.sh `"dir1 dir2"` dir3 dir4

Comment: What commands are you running in the script that you want to perform on 2 directories?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array of directories for this purpose like so:

```
## declare an array variable
declare -a arr=("/home/x/dir1" "/home/x/dir2" "/home/x/dir3")

## now loop through the above array
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
     ./myscript.sh $i dir3 dir4 ...
done
```

Answer (score 0):

How about merging the directory contents together in a separate script, and then passing that script as a parameter:

```
file1=$1
file2=$2
cp -R $file1/* $file2
echo $file2
```

Then you can use the script as follows:

```
./myscript "$(./merge dir1 dir2)" dir3 ...
```

Comment: Ah, so this explains [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27770137/2088135).

Comment: indeed, that's what prompted me to ask in the first place. I was surprised that there wasn't a question concerning this on SO