# bash - pass script as argument of another script

Tags: bash

I can't find a similar question on SO.

How can I properly pass a bash script as an argument to another bash script.

For example, let's say I have two scripts that can each accept a number of parameters, I want to pass one script as the argument of the other. Something like:

```
./script1 (./script2 file1 file2) file3
```

In the above example, script2 merges file1 and file2 together, and echos a new file, however that is irrelevant to the question. I just want to know how I can pass `script2` as a parameter, i.e. the proper syntax.

If this is not possible, any hint as to how I may circumvent the issue would be appropriate.

Comment: How do you intend to use the `script2`, once you have "passed" it to `script1`?

Comment: At the moment, I'm not quite sure, the `script1` I was using just iterates over all the contents of the parameters. But, I'm just interested in figuring out how I can pass the script as a parameter, because its not working for me.

Comment: It's still not clear to me what you're aiming to achieve, or what it really means to pass a script as a parameter. Parameters are just strings. Presumably you would like to run `script2` passing the file names `file1` and `file2` at some point. Would it be sufficient to pass the result of this action?

Comment: What I was aiming to achieve was basically @Cameron Martin 's answer.

Comment: In that case, why did you accept the other answer?

Comment: both answers work equally well, but I found j.a's answer more descriptive, and his was the one I chose to implement. I can't pick two best answers unfortunately.

Comment: It looks like [you chose to implement the other answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27770459/2088135).

Comment: yes, but even so, for this particular question, I still think the answer I chose as best answer is the better choice. More effort was put into it; he added code which I did not explicitly ask for, but was very useful nonetheless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to pass **script2** as an argument to **script1** to execute it inside the last one, just put the following code inside **script1** and call **script1** like this:

```
./script1 "./script2 file1 file2" file3  # file4 file5
```

Code inside **script1**:

```
$1 # here you're executing ./script2 file1 file2
shift
another_command "$@" # do anything else with the rest of params (file3)
```

---

Or if you know the number of params to **script2** and it is fixed, you can also do it as follows:

```
./script1 ./script2 file1 file2 file3  # file4 file5
```

Code inside **script1**:

```
"$1" "$2" "$3"
shift 3
another_command "$@" # do anything else with the rest of params (file3)
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to pass the result of evaluating script2 as a parameter, use `$()`. Remember that you have to quote it.

```
./script1 "$(./script2 file1 file2)" file3
```

Comment: Where _evaluating_ means _capturing the standard output as a single parameter_.